# Unable to read file from mounted directory in docker

Tags: docker, ocr, tesseract

I'm developing a project which accepts image (photos) as a input from user, perform OCR on it using command-line Tesseract-OCR, store result in text file as "input.txt", then perform stopword-removal on this file using java program. All this should be done inside docker container. I have created docker image with Tesseract OCR installed within it. I have working StopWord-Removal Java code.

In my project, I have mounted host-os directory as "/work" directory inside docker image, so that I can get "image (photos)" directly from users home directory as,

```
    docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/work -w /work ocr
```

here "ocr" is my docker image. I have created bash script, which calls Tessract-OCR and then calls StopWordRemoval java code, as

```
    #!/bin/bash
    tesseract sample.jpg input
    java StopWords
```

Problem is, output of "tesseract sample.jpg input" is saved as "input.txt", but it is not accessible inside java program, whereas if I try to open other files from given directory using same code it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file "input.txt" written to host mounted directory or to container filesystem? I assume that "input.txt" is successfully written. It will be good if you can try accessing the file "input.txt" outside Java to narrow down the issue.

Comment: yes, file is written into mounted host directory. I have tried different approaches at last I found one way. I have executed shell commands inside java. In my program I'm using "cat input.txt" and its output is stored in BufferedReader, later I processed that output.